# c# form - how to .onscroll with Autoscroll?

Tags: c#, scroll, autoscroll

How to create a function that activates when an autoscroll-scrollbar is used.

For explanation: I've got a form with Autoscroll = true, but scrollbars only start showing after a panel in the form is expanded by clicking a button. In other words, when designing, I don't see the scrollbars so can't click them to create a function.

BTW i'm using visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbars will only trigger when the child controls extend the dimensions of the parent control. For instance if a button is placed at y of 600 but the height if the form is 400, there will be 200+height of button scrollable distance on the form

Comment: Yes I know, my question is how to assign a function to them, since they're not visible in my designer so I can't click on them.